# OpenWebkitSharp and html5 local storage

Tags: c#, .net, webkit, open-webkit-sharp

I'm trying embed the openWebkitSharp (3.0.1.0023) library in a Windows Forms application.
Essentially, the app displays html pages and makes requests to the server through ajax.

We have a webserver which responses with html pages/css and javascript. 
We use data from that server for phonegap apps on android and ios. The webserver has functionality to generate a SQL query and send this back to the clients (browser/iphone/android) where it is executed and saved on the devices themselves. For data access, html5sql.js is used.

This all works flawlessly on all clients, except the desktop application.

I'm getting the following error when initiating the database:

> SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent. (html5sql.js:162)

I've came across a solution (http://gt-web-software.webs.com/apps/forums/topics/show/7651595-javascript-localstorage-not-persistent-) which probably worked for older versions of OWKS. However, in the newer version of OWKS, this does not apply anymore, since some classes have changed.

I've also tried to use the useragent string from my chrome browser, which didn't work either.

How can I enable OWKS to use the local storage feature of webkit?